# Scatter plot in R doesn't use the x values in the variable indicated in the plot statement

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot in R between two numeric variables, and it uses the observation number as the x variable. This is the problem I'm trying to fix: I would like to have a scatter plot that uses the values of the x variable I indicated in the plot statement. 
Yes, both the X variable and the Y variable are numeric.
I've attached a screenshot showing the data setup (Galton height data), the fact that the father and son variables are both numeric, and the resulting plot.
[image: screenshot of Galton height data setup and resulting plot]

Here's the code that sets up the data and runs the scatter plot:

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
library('dplyr')

#tidyverse is name of package used for class
library(tidyverse)
remove.packages('HistData')
install.packages('HistData')
library(HistData)
data("GaltonFamilies")
childNum <- galton_heights[,6]
gender <- galton_heights[,8]
#Different code to get son height
#If we wanted to follow the lesson exactly, we would
#use the following
son_data <- GaltonFamilies[GaltonFamilies$gender == "male" & GaltonFamilies$childNum == 1,]
son <- son_data$childHeight

#Now we can compare the oldest child's height (if they happen to be male) with that of the father:
GaltonFamilies %>% summarize(mean(father), sd(father), mean(son), sd(son))
GaltonFamilies$father2 <- as.numeric(GaltonFamilies$father)
#galton_heights$father <- as.numeric(levels(galton_heights$father))[galton_heights$father]
plot(GaltonFamilies$father,GaltonFamilies$son)
plot(GaltonFamilies$father2, GaltonFamilies$son, main="Scatterplot Example", 
     xlab="Father ", ylab="Son ")
```

Edit: the filter statement creating son_data wasn't working when I ran the above code fresh. I don't know why. I've replaced it with a way to get son_data without the filter.
son_data <- GaltonFamilies[GaltonFamilies$gender == "male" & GaltonFamilies$childNum == 1,]

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and the actual code (not a screenshot of the code). That will help us figure out the problem and help you.

Comment: Maybe it's something in the tidyverse or dplyr packages? I can get a scatter plot of numeric variables if I don't use those packages. 
#Ignoring the code limiting it to son height because this comment doesn't have room       library(HistData)
data("GaltonFamilies")
plot(GaltonFamilies$father,GaltonFamilies$childHeight)

Comment: Are you aware that none of the code before the plot call (except for `data("GaltonFamilies")` actually affects the plot, right?

Comment: There is no GaltonFamilies$son. I don't even know why it's giving you any output at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `GaltonFamilies$son`. See also: [Random data added when using `plot` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837553/random-data-added-when-using-plot-in-r)

Comment: So I had a 'son' variable, but it wasn't attached to GaltonFamilies. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `son` is probably not the same length as GaltonFamilies, because it was created from a subset of it. In this case, I would recommend working with the `son_data` data.frame, rather than separating `son` away from it.