# Random data added when using `plot` in R

Tags: r, plot

I came across this by accident, and I have no idea what's going on. Can anyone explain this?

```
plot(iris$Petal.Length,iris$foobar)
```

produces this:

[image]

Even though there is no `iris$foobar`, or even just a `foobar` object. Where is this y-axis data coming from? I've encountered this with another data.frame, so this is not unique to iris (in fact, I tried it on iris to see if there was something amiss with my other data.frame). And how come the x-axis is labeled as "Index"?

Version data:
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          4.3
year           2017
month          11
day            30
svn rev        73796
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree

```
loadedNamespaces()
 [1] "Rcpp"         "HistData"     "bindr"        "magrittr"    
 [5] "grDevices"    "tidyselect"   "munsell"      "wordcloud"   
 [9] "colorspace"   "R6"           "rlang"        "stringr"     
[13] "plyr"         "dplyr"        "tools"        "utils"       
[17] "grid"         "gtable"       "stats"        "datasets"    
[21] "yaml"         "lazyeval"     "assertthat"   "tibble"      
[25] "base"         "bindrcpp"     "purrr"        "RColorBrewer"
[29] "ggplot2"      "tidyr"        "graphics"     "glue"        
[33] "slam"         "stringi"      "compiler"     "pillar"      
[37] "methods"      "scales"       "lubridate"    "pkgconfig"   
[41] "Cairo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d$foobar` is being ignored by `plot()`, because `iris$foobar` is `NULL`.

It's simply plotting the petal length, with on the x-axis the index.

Compare with `plot(iris$Petal.Length)` or `plot(iris$Petal.Length, NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks. How come it's not throwing an error? And what's the index?

Comment: See @HolgerBarlt why there is no error. The index is the row number.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems there is no foobar in a data.frame, since you get the same plot when only calling `plot(iris$Petal.Length)`. Since the second argument is null `is.null(iris$foobar)` it will just be ignored....